# How to check maven version in Azure devops for specific project?

Tags: azure, maven, azure-devops, deployment, settings

In order to resolve maven plugin I saw some suggestion to set maven plugin using Azure devops.Can any one suggest to set maven plugin in azure

To set Maven plugin in Azure environment so that maven plugin will not block Azure deployment

Comment: Agree with @Arko. In addition, if you have specific maven plugin error, it's recommended to elaborate a bit, you can add error message, screenshot and pipeline task definition...etc.

Answer (score 0):

To check the Maven version used in a specific project in Azure DevOps, you can either view the build [YAML](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/riyafa/transport-http/076cca9978202d8ceb630b7ff8b419e408659981/azure-pipelines.yml) file to find the step where Maven is being used. Look for a section where `mvn` command is executed or check the build logs. When Maven runs, it typically prints out its version.

[image]

Generally Azure DevOps provides hosted agents with a range of software pre-installed, including Maven. The 'Default' Maven version is the one that comes pre-installed on these agents.
If you need a specific version of Maven, you can modify the `mavenVersionOption` in your YAML file to specify a different version instead of using the 'Default' setting.

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'Ubuntu 16.04'

steps:
- script: 'wget http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.5.4/binaries/apache-maven-3.5.4-bin.zip'

- task: ExtractFiles@1
  inputs:
      archiveFilePatterns: 'apache-maven-3.5.4-bin.zip'
      destinationFolder: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)/maven'

- task: Maven@3
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    goals: 'clean install -P ballerina'
    mavenVersionOption: 'Path'
    mavenDirectory: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)/maven/apache-maven-3.5.4'
    mavenSetM2Home: true
```

[image]

[image]